# Comparing strength of correlation and cointegration

Tags: time-series, correlation, cointegration

I am doing analysis of time series of returns on various currency pairs, commodities and stocks in **Python/R** and **I would like to compare the strength of cointegration and correlation (Spearman's) between the various assets**.

Basically I would like to show quantitatively that those two differ and how much for the corresponding assets. To my knowledge I have not seen a cointegration measure of strength that would allow me to do so. The only idea I have had was the significance of the cointegration test, but I do not know how I would then compare it to the correlation.

Comment: Returns are typically I(0) to begin with, so there is no place for cointegration among returns (but there is among prices).

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have not made myself clear. That is what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correlation can be strong or weak, and this is reflected by the location of its absolute value in the range between zero and one (close to zero - weak, close to one - strong).

Cointegration is a yes/no phenomenon. Either it exists or it does not. Either there is a linear combination of integrated variables that has a lower order of integration, or not. You cannot quantify its strength.
The significance of cointegration test measures the confidence with which you can make statements about presence/absence of cointegration; but that is not quite the same as measuring the strength of cointegration.
What you could probably do as an alternative is examine how fast/intensive the error correction mechanism works (how fast the gap from the equilibrium closes).